# How to optimize nested conditional SQL Server Query 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
if {condition1} = '0'
begin
    if  {condition2} = 'Yes'
        Begin
            Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND  '
        end
    else 
        begin
            Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND  '
        end
end
```

Comment: Use `CASE` instead...

Comment: @pranav SELECT Notes FROM tab1 WHERE Notes <> '' 
CASE WHEN @ LocID > 0 AND @ Seell  = 'Yes' THEN 
 AND (PID)=@ LocID <Need to append this to my SQL>
ELSE AND ( (PID)=@ LocID or (C.LocID)=@ LocID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pranav states in the comments, you can do the following:

```
if {condition1} = '0'
  Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND ' +
                  CASE WHEN {condition2} = 'Yes' THEN <whatever cond2=Yes>
                       ELSE <whatever cond2<>Yes> END
```

Comment: thanks for the answer can we make a similar SQL statement without dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, just assign any or empty value to @SQLQuery before running this

```
SELECT @SQLQuery+ = CASE WHEN CONDITION1='0' AND CONDITION2='Yes' THEN
' AND '
WHEN CONDITION1='0' THEN
' AND '
END
```